# GSON: expected a String but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 4115. What is 4115 here?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Whenever somebody gets the error while parsing using GSON he may get the following error: "IllegalArgumentException : expected a String but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 4115". I think that there might be some error in models.

My question is how to identify the error if the JSON data is quite large and what   the column number 4115 means?

Thanks!

Comment: not valid json. try to log response

Comment: Paste your code snippet  what exactly you did ?

Comment: "Autocrab" json might be valid, but model class not correct. Based on described error there is probably in JSON nested array of objects and not just simple String as is expected in model class.

Comment: Apparently your server json response doesn't break lines ("column 4115"). It's not possible to help without looking at the actual response.